# Restrict URL Paramater by htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to restrict parameter by htaccess below are the example which i want to achieve

This parameter is valid & htaccess rule will be allowing it

```
example.com/test?param=somevalue
```

This parameter should be restrict OR change parameter name by htaccess

Parameter Sample URL

```
example.com/test?param[]=somevalue
```

Redirect to

```
example.com/test?param=somevalue
```

OR

```
example.com/test
```

I tried some rules of htaccess and restricting parameter without these bracket

```
[]
```

but i'm not able to restrict parameters which containing [] in name.

Comment: Please tag appropriately. `devops` has not connection to this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the brackets by escaping them in the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(foo)(?:\[\])?=(.*)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1=%2
```

This rewrites `https://example.com/test?foo[]=bar` to `https://example.com/test?foo=bar`.

Note however that there is a sematic meaning for parameters with a trailing "[]" for php applications (and maybe others): those parameters are provided as *arrays* to the requested resource. And they potentially occur multiple times in a request's query string, which is why they are names in such manner. So take care that you don't break the application logic by this parameter modification.

Comment: this rule detect both `foo[]` and `foo` & due to which it's going on infinite loop

Comment: @user3409089 I do not see an infinite loop here ... Yes, the pattern also matches the rewritten query string, but a loop only starts when the subject is actually altered. Which is not the case here. Anyway, this was not meant as a snippet you can simply copy to solve all problems, but to demonstrate how to capture those brackets. Which is what you asked, as I understand your question. To me it is not clear from the question what you actually want to achieve which is why I focused on the actual specific issue you named: "but i'm not able to restrict parameters which containing [] in name"

Comment: @user3409089 If this really somehow creates a rewriting loop for you then you can simply remove the "?" in the pattern that makes the brackets optional.